# HTML5 Video Fullscreen mode - video way off center

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I have a video that does a "faux" fullscreen animation. It animates to full screen width (and as much height as it can) when an image is clicked.

Here is the false fullscreen:
 [image: False Fullscreen]

Here is what happens when I click the built in fullscreen icon on the video itself:

[image: Real Fullscreen]

I am using the script which is found here: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/VideoOpeningAnimation/

It seems that the provided script has similar problems to me (but it doesn't have controls enabled by default)

I didn't think a video's CSS style in fullscreen mode could be overridden? What is happening here?

CSS:

```js
 $(".action--play").on('click', function (e) {
  
  $(".video-wrap").addClass('video-wrap--show');
  $(".video-wrap").removeClass('video-wrap--hide');

  
  $('#videos')[0].play();
  
 });
 $(".action--close").on('click', function (e) {
  $(".video-wrap").addClass('video-wrap--hide');
  $(".video-wrap").removeClass('video-wrap--show');

  var video = document.getElementById('videos');
  video.pause();
  video.currentTime = 0;
  
 });
```

```css
.video-wrap {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 pointer-events: none;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.video-wrap--show {
 pointer-events: auto;
}

.video-inner {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 opacity: 0;
 background: black;
}

.video-wrap--show .video-inner {
 opacity: 1;
}

.video-player {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 height: auto;
 width:100%;
 left:0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0);
}

.video-wrap--show .action--close {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 1.2s;
 transition-delay: 1.2s;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.video-wrap--show {
 pointer-events: auto;
}

.video-wrap--show .video-inner {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-wrap">
  <div class="video-inner">
    <video class="video-player" src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4" poster="assets/vid/media/woods.jpg" preload="auto" controls id="videos">
      <source src="assets/vid/media/woods.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'>
      <source src="assets/vid/woods.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'>
      <p>Sorry, but your browser does not support this video format.</p>
    </video>
    <button class="action action--close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i><span class="action__label action__label--hidden">Close preview</span></button>
  </div> <!-- /video-inner -->
</div><!-- /video-wrap-->


<img src="assets/images/play.png" id="play-button" class="action--play">
```

Comment: Please, he means. Upload your code please.

Comment: Will add it in. Sorry !

Comment: I've just figured out at workaround, whilst not a direct solution to my problem, I discovered it by using the code snippet! I can hide the fullscreen toggle on HTML5 videos by using the following CSS: video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: none;
}

Comment: Update - I think this only works on chrome :(